# How do I automatically adjust my parent div around children divs?

Tags: html, css

I apologize for any confusion that may arise from this question, I am just dipping my toes into html and any help is appreciated.

To specify which elements I'm talking about, I've put their CSS selectors inside parenthesis to try to eliminate confusion. For some reason my parent div `#box_one div{}` is adjusting according to it's child div's height, but not it's width.

For instance, the child div's `#box_one div{} > div` height is `100px`, so it's parent adjusted to that height, plus the extra padding. But when I change the child div's `#box_one div > div` width to `20px`, the parent div 
`#box_one div{}` remains unchanged and it's width is according to the outermost parent `#box_one`.

```css
#box_one {
  border: 3px outset #eee;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: #eee;
  padding-top: 1%;
  padding-bottom: 1%;
  padding: 10px;
}
#box_one div {
  margin-top: 20px;
  border: inset;
  padding: 5%;
}
#box_one div>div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0px;
}
p {
  text-align: center;
  border-style: inset;
  margin-top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Text</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="website.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="box_one">
    <p>This is some text.</p>
    <div>
      <div></div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `#box_one div` actually selects two divs as it matches any div that is a descendant of `#box_one`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A block element will take up all of the available width by default, and be 0 height by default. So a parent element will always be 100% width unless defined otherwise, but only as tall as it's children.

If you want the parent width to conform to that of it's children, you can assign either `float` (like `float: left;`) or `display: inline-block;` to the parent.

```css
* {box-sizing:border-box;}
#box_one {
  border: 3px outset #eee;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: #eee;
  padding-top: 1%;
  padding-bottom: 1%;
  padding: 10px;
  float: left;
}
#box_one div {
  margin-top: 20px;
  border: inset;
  padding: 5%;
}
#box_one div>div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0px;
}
p {
  text-align: center;
  border-style: inset;
  margin-top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Text</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="website.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="box_one">
    <p>This is some text.</p>
    <div>
      <div></div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make it an `inline-block`  and erase all width and height settings from its CSS. But in this case make sure the children have content and/or fixed widths and heights:

```css
#box_one{
    border:3px outset #eee;
    margin:10px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #eee;
    padding-top: 1%;
    padding-bottom: 1%;
    padding:10px;
}
#box_one div{
    margin-top:20px; 
    border:inset;
    padding: 5%;    
}

#box_one div>div{
    height: 100px;  
    width:200px;
    margin:0px; }

p{
    text-align: center;
    border-style:inset; 
    margin-top:0px;
}
```

```html
    <head>  
        <title>Text</title> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="website.css">
    </head>
     <body> 
        <div id="box_one">
            <p>This is some text.</p>
            <div>
                <div></div>
            </div>
        </div>

     </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Divs are block elements and try to take up as much space horizontally as possible, so in effect it takes up the width of it's parent's div, if a certain width is not specified.

The height of the div is defined by the child's height, but the width will be defined by it's parent's width.  To adjust a div around it's children, it's best to set the parent div's width to whatever is the width that you need, and set the child div's width to 100% and the child's height to the height you need, or add the content you need, the height of which will be adopted by both divs.

```
div.parent {
   width: 20px;
}
div.child {
   width: 100%;
   height: 50px;
}

<div class="parent">
     <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set inside the largest children element:

```css
display: contents;
```